# How to post only variable with values and ignore blank inputs in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

Forms input value variables are the same changing only labels for it from DB. When form selected other ones is hidden with "style.display = "none".
The problem that I face how to prevent sending empty values from none visible input fields?
Tried a trim function but didn't work for me. Maybe didn't use it correctly.
I'm trying to accomplish that input value would stay the same regardless of what user would select and only labels would change.
[dump output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o2Hp.png)

```php
<?php
if (isset($_POST["save"])) {

    if (empty($_POST['price'])) {
        $error["price"] = "Price Required";
    } else {
        $price = $_POST["price"];
    }
    if (array_filter($error)) {
        echo "Input error";
    } else {
        $price = ($_POST['price']);
        $value1 = ($_POST['value1']) ?? null;
        $value2 = $_POST['value2'] ?? null;
        $value3 = $_POST['value3'] ?? null;
    }
}

// insert size
$sql = "INSERT INTO valueSize(value1, value2, value3) values('$value1', '$value2, '$value3')";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<form action="">
    <?php foreach ($categoriesTypeId as $key): ?>
    <div class="dropItem invisible" id="<?php echo $key['id'] ?>">
        <label for="value1"><?php echo $key['value1Type'] ?>:</label>
        <input type="text" name="value1[]" value="<?php echo $value1 ?>">
        <div class="error"><?php echo $error['value1'] ?></div>
        <?php if (isset($key['value2Type'])) {?>
        <div class="inputCheck">
            <label for="value2"><?php echo $key['value2Type'] ?>
                :</label>
            <input type="text" name="value2" value="<?php echo $value2 ?>">
            <div class="error"><?php echo $error['value2'] ?></div>
        </div>
        <?php
}
;
?>

        <?php if (isset($key['value3Type'])) {?>
        <div class="inputCheck">
            <label for="value3"><?php echo $key['value3Type'] ?>
                :</label>
            <input type="text" name="value3" value="<?php echo $value3 ?>">
            <div class="error"><?php echo $error['value3'] ?></div>
        </div>
        <?php
} else {
}
?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, if you set the hidden inputs to disabled, their values won't get sent. Is that an option for you?

Comment: Yeah, that an option. I could definitely use it with javascript. Thanks, Jonnix. But I wonder how could it accomplish it with PHP?! Because in this coding design I can disable input fields because input fields stay the same, label and information changes.

Comment: Warning: you are using a [cargo cult prepared statement](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/cargo_cult_prepared_statement) that doesn't protect anything. Use placeholders in the prepared query instead.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. What does it mean, " input value would stay the same"? this sentence only makes sense client-side. How is this question related to PHP? What "input value" you are talking about? And what does it mean, "Tried a trim function but didn't work"? Tried what for and what was the result?